# Rotate Tikz-UML sequence diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating, tikz-uml

I'm trying to rotate a Tikz-UML sequence diagram by 90 degrees, but the lay-out is completely screwed up when I do. At the moment, I use following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=90]
\begin{umlseqdiag}
    \umlobject[no ddots]{Application}
    \umlcreatecall[no ddots, x=4]{Application}{ProfilePageGUI}
    \umlcreatecall[no ddots, x=7]{ProfilePageGUI}{RemoveUserDialog}
    \umlcreatecall[no ddots, x=10]{ProfilePageGUI}{ConfirmUserDeletionDialog}
    \umlobject[no ddots, x=13]{User}
    \begin{umlcall}[op={openProfilePage()}, return=""]{Application}{ProfilePageGUI}
    \end{umlcall}
\end{umlseqdiag}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The horizontal (original, without rotation) version looks like this:
[image]

But, when I rotate it, it looks like this:
[image]

Is there a different way to rotate this image? I want to do this, because I don't have enough horizontal space for the full diagram.

EDIT: I updated the code to make it compile.

Comment: Can you give an MWE?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes The code in my post, should work. I can give you another diagram that's complete if you want.

Comment: The code as it is given at the moment is not compilable. @StevenB.Segletes was asking for a minimal working example, which means a fully and without errors compileable code illustrating your problem, starting with `\documentclass...` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Do I understand correct, that you like to have rotated image that it can be fit in a page? if this is the case, than try to insert image in for example `sidewaysfigure` environment or encapsulate it in `\rotatebox{90}{\begin{tikzpicture} ...\end{tikzpicture}}`.

Comment: Yes indeed, I want to rotate it to make it fit. I will try your solution! Thank you very much :)

Comment: Add the necessary packages to make your code compilable, otherwise we have to spend time looking for those instead of solving the problem.

Comment: @Alenanno I'm sorry I will include them.

Comment: Well, I'm glad to hear this. I will convert my comment to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, you looking for rotating complete image as such. This you can achieve on the two ways:

- use `\rotatebox{<angle>}{ ... }` from package `graphicx`
- use `sidewaysfigure` environmnent from package `rotating`

I'm sorry, but I can't provide MWE with your code since some used package are not available in my MikTeX repository.